# How to mount sdcard permanently?

Tags: android, usb-drive

Is there any way to write data to a sdcard, when the card is mounted as a disc via USB?

If I unplug it, everything is fine. How do I solve this problem? Anybody ideas or sample code?

Comment: Do you realise you've written a 5 line **single** sentence? Getting to the end is a real chore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android allows only one mount at a time, so if you connect your device via USB and provide the card as a mount for your pc, android unmounts the card from the OS. That behavior cant be changed by an application and shouldnt be changed in the name of the data security.

Comment: @have any coding for mount sdcard using USB

Comment: and here I go again: you can't mount an sd card which is connected via USB. Android unmount the sd card if you give it free for usb usage. That means that as long as the USB connection is available and the card is mounted by your connected PC, you can't access the sd card. Anyway the mount/unmount of an sdcard should be handled by android OS, not your application. You can only check the state of the sdcard...

Comment: @ok i understand,for example device camera shot image and store in sdcard,How?

Comment: try to search, plenty of questions and answers here on stackoverflow...