# How to store image in sdcard at any time

Tags: android

I am developing an application for an image gallery. I am using the share option in my application. The share option function is share image in SDcard, for example particular image I share, that image store in sdcard. When the user clicks the share button that time image will store in SDcard, images are retrieved from a url. Have any idea, anbody knows please give code for anytime can store image in sdcard.

Thanks All

Comment: I gave you here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726332/how-to-mount-sdcard-permentaly ) the advice to use the search function, and you started a new question? ... how can someone be so immune to advices...

Comment: What is your question? I can't see what already is done and what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3); 
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
values.put(Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "Bs_image"+tit+".PNG");
values.put(Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");               
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
 OutputStream outStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
outStream.close();
```

It is work fine..